# Spawning Node with an asar-archived file

Tags: javascript, node.js

In an app where most files are packaged in an Asar archive (nodejs.js isn't) I'm trying to spawn a node process while passing it a file, that is this time, packaged.

My folder structure is like this:

- nodejs.js
- app.asar

  - myfile.js

And here is my code:

```
 this.fileToPass = join(this.$.env.app.root, 'main.js'); 
 //The path is now something like: directory/app.asar/main.js
 var self = this;

 /***************/
 //Some more code
 /**************/

 self.process = spawn('/path/to/node', [self.fileToPass], {
    env: self.config
    // stdio: 'inherit'
 });
```

However I keep hitting this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/directory/app.asar/app/main.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

I am at my wit's end. What could be causing this behavior? Is there some way to circumvent this issue?

PS: fork as well is not really an option, given that I need to pipe stdout and stderr later on.

Thank you.